# Fraction exponential limit in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let $n$ be an integer.  I need to compute the limit $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 2n\pi i}\dfrac{e^z-1}{z-2n\pi i}$$ for complex number $z$. I think I can't use L'Hospital here since $z$ is complex. How can I do it?

Comment: This limit is divergent.

Comment: I think I missed a factor of $2$. Is it convergent now?

Comment: No. It is also divergent. I think $2n\pi$ is modified to $2n\pi i$.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** use the definition of the derivative at a point.

> $$ f'(z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} .$$

Comment: Oh right, it's the reciprocal of the derivative of the function $e^z$!

Answer (score 1):

By the Taylor series of $e^z$
$$e^z=e^{z-2n\pi i}=1+(z-2n\pi i)+(z-2n\pi i)^2\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(z-2n\pi i)^{n-2}$$
So
$$\frac{e^z-1}{z-2n\pi i}=1+(z-2n\pi i)\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(z-2n\pi i)^{n-2}.$$
You can check that if $|z-2n\pi i|<1$ then
$$\left|\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(z-2n\pi i)^{n-2} \right|\le e-2$$
so
$$\lim_{z\to 2n\pi i}\frac{e^z-1}{z-2n\pi i}=1.$$